# How to do another transaction only after first transaction is successful in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
customerReference.document(customerName).set(customerDetails).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            customerReference.document(customerName).collection(firebaseUser.getUid())
                    .document(invoiceDate + " && " + timestampString).set(makeBillDetails)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                openPdf();
                        }
```

So now what I am doing is setting an object to a document and after getting success for that transaction, I am doing some other transaction. This is working great when online but when the transaction occur in offline mode, first transaction will be done locally but listeners(success or failure) will not be triggered so how to do second transaction now?

Comment: Transactions do not work offline, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

In your code above, you're using `set` which is not transactional on its own. To start a transaction use `db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {....` See the docs for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your code is not called transactions. You are only using the `set()` method to add object to the database.

So, when there is a loss of network connectivity (there is no network connection on user device), neither `onSuccess()` nor `onFailure()` are triggered. This is the behaviour in `Cloud Firestore` and has also always been in the `Firebase Realtime Database`. Only writes that are committed on Firebasee server are considered failed/succeeded.

Firestore provides this feature for handle offline data but you need to use a `addSnapshotListener`, in order to handle this case.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Then how to set data like what I am doing in code given in the question in offline mode? Like creating a document and setting data to that document and then after creating of first document, second document will be added within a sub collection under first document

Comment: Cloud Firestore has offline persistence set to `true` by default. So you can do it in the exaxt way you do it. What is wrong with your code?

Comment: If the device is offline it will not come in onSucess method then how to set second document under first one. This is wrong in the code that I am creating a document and set some data under that and then coming in OnSuccess method I am creating another document but when offline it will never come in onSucess method

Comment: I understand but there is no way in which you can achieve this and this is because while the device is offline, `onSuccess()` is not triggered. That write operation will remain in a queue until the device will again internet connectivity. In that moment the `onSuccess()` method is triggred and the second method is called. `onSuccess()` is useless while you are offline. Cloud Firestore database is really designed as an online database that came work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected. So the only way to achieve this is to give your phone again internet access.